# handle the event on click and toggle the button color on react webchat

Tags: reactjs, botframework, direct-line-botframework, web-chat

I was trying some work around on react webchat for feedback option. I got a lead from one of the team member in Microsoft to fulfill my requirement. here is the link of github where I requested for feature.
https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/3102

In this I got the solution but still there is one thing which is lagging and I am unable to understand the approach to handle the same.

1. onclick of thumbs up the background color is changing to green color(this is working).
2. onclick of thumbs down the background color is changing to red color(this is working).
3. onclick of thumbs up or thumbs down if any of the button is already clicked remove the color of the button and add the latest click. for example: I clicked on thumbs up for one message bubble and again clicked on thumbs down for the same message bubble, in this scenario the thumbs up button color should get removed and should set to default and thumbs down color should append and vice versa.

I am pasting the code snippet here:

```
const activityStatusMiddleware = () => next => args => {
            const { activity, activity: { from: { role }, value }, sendState, sameTimestampGroup } = args;
            const reactionButtons = document.body.getElementsByClassName( 'botActivityDecorator__button' );
            window.handleEvent = function(event) {
                const { srcElement: { classList, textContent }, type } = event;
                if (type === 'click') {
                    switch (textContent) {
                        case '':
                            if (!event.srcElement.classList.contains( 'reaction_positive' )) {
                                event.srcElement.classList.add( 'reaction_positive' )
                            }
                        break;
                        case '':
                            if (!event.srcElement.classList.contains( 'reaction_negative' )) {
                                event.srcElement.classList.add( 'reaction_negative' )
                            }
                        break;
                        default:
                            event.srcElement.classList.remove( 'reaction_positive' )
                            event.srcElement.classList.remove( 'reaction_negative' )
                    }
                }
            }
            for ( let i = 0; i <= reactionButtons.length - 1; i++ ) {
                reactionButtons[ i ].addEventListener( 'click', window, false)
            }
```

Comment: I'm the same fellow who helped provide the solution in the above link you referenced. I'll update that issue to reflect the new code.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that I use (placed in the `activityStatusMiddleware()`). It allows for toggling between up voting and down voting, per bot response.

```js
if (role === 'bot') {
  const reactionBtns = document.querySelectorAll( '.botActivityDecorator__button' );
  let btnIndex = 0
  if (reactionBtns.length > 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i <= reactionBtns.length - 1; i++) {
      reactionBtns[ i ].onclick = () => {
        if (reactionBtns[ i ].classList.contains( 'reaction_positive' ) && reactionBtns[ i ].innerText === '') {
          reactionBtns[ i ].classList.remove( 'reaction_positive' );
        } else if (!reactionBtns[ i ].classList.contains( 'reaction_positive' ) && reactionBtns[ i ].innerText === '') {
          reactionBtns[ i ].classList.add( 'reaction_positive' );
          reactionBtns[ i + 1 ].classList.remove( 'reaction_negative' );
        }

        if (reactionBtns[ i ].classList.contains( 'reaction_negative' ) && reactionBtns[ i ].innerText === '') {
          reactionBtns[ i ].classList.remove( 'reaction_negative' );
        } else if (!reactionBtns[ i ].classList.contains( 'reaction_negative' ) && reactionBtns[ i ].innerText === '') {
          reactionBtns[ i ].classList.add( 'reaction_negative' );
          reactionBtns[ i - 1 ].classList.remove( 'reaction_positive' );
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Hope of help!